# What is "applessdstatistics" doing on my non-SSD, non-Fusion drive iMac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac

I have a mid-2010 iMac that has regular HDD (not a Fusion drive, just good old spinning disks). Recently, after reboot, I was hearing intensive HDD I/O sounds and firing up Activity Monitor I noticed `applessdstatistics` process was reading a lot of data.

I [found a way to disable it](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7798092?start=0&tstart=0) via Terminal command:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.applessdstatistics.plist
```

But the question is: what was the process doing on my computer in the first place?

Does it do any tasks that would—nevermind the process name—benefit a regular HDD? Meaning: should I re-enable it?

I'm on up-to-date macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For whatever reason *applessdstatistics* started appearing for many non-SSD users after the macOS Sierra 10.12.2 update. **Apple is aware of the issue.**

As you've discovered, if you do not have an SSD it is totally safe to disable *applessdstatistics* with:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.applessdstatistics.plist
```

And no, there is no need for you to re-enable it.

**[EDIT]**

After reading the comments I thought I should add some additional info about this issue.

Based on the advice provided by Apple on 8 February 2017, there are actually two issues that appeared around the same time concerning *applessdstatistics*. I describe these below:

1. The first issue is the one directly referred to in the OP's question. This is the issue of Macs with only hard drives suddenly having *applessdstatistics* appear and start reading data from the hard drive (typically in 4GB lots). *applessdstatistics* is only supposed to run on Macs with a SSD installed, not on Macs with traditional hard drives installed. This issue has affected a large number of desktop users with internal hard drives, primarily older iMacs (although this may only be because there are more iMacs in the field compared to Mac Pros and Mac Minis). I am unaware as to whether it is affecting MacBook models with only hard drives installed (as Little Eden implies in their comment below), but I am aware of the following issue (see 2 below) which could be what Little Eden is referring to.
2. The second issue, however, does affect various MacBooks (and other Macs) which do have a SSD installed. The issue is **not** the presence of *applessdstatistics* and the fact it is running, but the fact it results in high CPU usage. *applessdstatistics* has been running in the background of Macs with SSDs installed for a long time without issue until macOS Sierra 10.12.2 was released. However, after this release it has resulted in high CPU usage and, in some cases, a noticeable amount of noise coming from the machine.

**Notes:**

- The 2nd issue (re high CPU usage and noise levels) is also affecting some non-SSD Macs affected by the first issue.
- It is my understanding that Apple has an open ticket on this issue (i.e. I *think* it's the one ticket for both issues as they're related) and that a future update will resolve this.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information, especially that Apple is aware of the issue?

Comment: @grgarside Hmm, not sure if there's anything in the public domain (I haven't looked). My _source_ was direct communication with Apple on 8 February 2017 during which I was advised they had an open ticket on the issue. This has affected a large number of desktop users with internal hard drives, primarily older iMacs. When I say a large number, it is a minority of users overall, but large enough that it's been flagged by Apple and will be addressed in an update.

Comment: @Monomeeth is correct. I work for a large organisation that has a dedicated video production unit and dedicated design studio that use Apple Macs. We noticed this issue on about half the iMacs and when we raised it with IT and they raised it with Apple, we were told it was a known issue and Apple is investigating it. One thing though, some of the MacBook Pros also started having issues with this, so it's not just desktop Macs.

Comment: @Little.Eden Thanks for your comment. It prompted me to update my answer to provide some additional info I was aware of. :)